# Inline checkbox label with Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

How do you get the table on a checkbox field to display inline with the checkbox (on the same horizontal line)?

```
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="consent">You must accept the <Link to={'/Terms'}>Terms of Use</Link> and <Link to={'/Privacy'}>Privacy Policy</Link></label>
                    <Field name="consent"  type="checkbox" className={'form-control' + (errors.consent && touched.consent ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                    <ErrorMessage name="consent" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                </div>
```

Note - I tried standard CSS before I asked this question. I can't see where to force the style to inline:

```
const style4 = {
    display: 'inline-block'
}
```

**Trying with standard CSS on the form group**

```
            <div className="form-group" style={style4}  >
                <label  htmlFor="consent">You must accept the <Link to={'/Terms'}>Terms of Use</Link> and <Link to={'/Privacy'}>Privacy Policy</Link> </label>
                <Field name="consent" type="checkbox" className={'form-control' + (errors.consent && touched.consent ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                <ErrorMessage name="consent" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
            </div>
```

**Trying with standard CSS on the form group label**

```
<div className="form-group" >
                        <label style={style4}  htmlFor="consent">You must accept the <Link to={'/Terms'}>Terms of Use</Link> and <Link to={'/Privacy'}>Privacy Policy</Link> </label>
                        <Field name="consent" type="checkbox" className={'form-control' + (errors.consent && touched.consent ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                        <ErrorMessage name="consent" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                    </div>
```

**Trying with standard CSS on the form group field**

```
<div className="form-group" >
                    <label  htmlFor="consent">You must accept the <Link to={'/Terms'}>Terms of Use</Link> and <Link to={'/Privacy'}>Privacy Policy</Link> </label>
                    <Field name="consent" style={style4} type="checkbox" className={'form-control' + (errors.consent && touched.consent ? ' is-invalid' : '')} />
                    <ErrorMessage name="consent" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it helps someone:

Form.css

```
.checkbox_label_wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

.links {
  margin: 0px 2px;
}
```

Form group:

```
<div className="form-group">
                <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
                    <Field
                      name="consent"
                      type="checkbox"
                      checked={values.consent}
                      className={
                        "checkbox" +
                        (errors.consent && touched.consent ? " is-invalid" : "")
                      }
                    />
                <label htmlFor="consent" className="checkbox_label_wrapper">
                  You must accept the{" "}
                  <Link className="links" to={"/Terms"}>
                    Terms of Use
                  </Link>{" "}
                  and{" "}
                  <Link className="links" to={"/Privacy"}>
                    Privacy Policy
                  </Link>



            </label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a `css` issue. Add `display: inline-block` to the element which you want to stay in the same line

Comment: It doesn't work. There must be something about Formik or react or react-bootstrap that is stopping it from working. I've tried adding that to each line in the form group and the box still appears under the label.